# closeDatabase()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I got a problem on my code, it says

> 07-22 21:40:43.059 28529-28529/plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> > Process: plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia, PID: 28529
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia/plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia.MainNotes}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia.NotesCRUDManager.closeDatabase()' on a null object reference
> >                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4874)
> >                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4892)
> >                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:218)
> >                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1772)
> >                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> >                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
> >                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
> >                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> >                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
> >                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
> >                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia.NotesCRUDManager.closeDatabase()' on a null object reference
> >                                                                                                    at plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia.MainNotes.onDestroy(MainNotes.java:60)

This is my **NotesCRUDManager.java**, database.

```
    public class NotesCRUDManager {

        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private Context context;
        private String DBName = "NotesDB";
        private String TableName = "mynotes";
        private List<Integer> ids_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private List<String> titles_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<String> notes_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<String> remark_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        NotesCRUDManager(Context context) {

            this.context = context;
            // As soon as we call this class our database should be created or opened
            AccessDatabase();
            AccessNotesTable();
        }

        // Opening database
        public void AccessDatabase() {
            // create database named as "Catalog"
            // context.MODE_PRIVATE indicates this database can only be access through this application
            db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        }

        // Selecting our table
        public void AccessNotesTable() {

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, note TEXT, remark TEXT)");
        }

        // Inserting product into table
        public void InsertNote(String title, String note, String remark) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); // create an instance of ContentValues
            values.put("title", title); // parameters are (key, value) but the key = columnName in our Database Table
            values.put("note", note);
            values.put("remark", remark);
            //db.insert() is similar to prepared statement in Java. It will prevent SQL Injections
            db.insert(TableName, null, values);
        }

        public void EditNote(int id, String title, String note, String remark) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); // create an instance of ContentValues
            values.put("title", title); // parameters are (key, value) but the key = columnName in our Database Table
            values.put("note", note);
            values.put("remark", remark);
            //db.update removes the risk of SQL Injection
            db.update(TableName, values, "_id = ?", new String[]{"" + id});
        }

        public void DeleteNote(int id) {
            // simple sql statement
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TableName + " WHERE _id = " + id + ";");
        }

        // Showing all rows from table
        public void showNote(List<Integer> ids_list, List<String> titles_list, List<String> notes_list, List<String> remark_list) {

            // this will execute select query
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " ORDER BY _id DESC", null);
            // getting data from all rows
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                //filling up the arraylist with database columns
                ids_list.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                titles_list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                notes_list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                remark_list.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }

        }

        // Relesing database object
        public void closeDatabase() {
            // close the database, always remember only close the database when it is opened
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

This is my **MainNotes.java**, noteslist seems like the error for me. But I don't know how to change my code. .

```
public class MainNotes extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private NotesCRUDManager nmanager;
    private Button create, clear, noteslist;
    private EditText title, note, remark;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_notes);

        create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
        clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        noteslist = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_shownotes);
        title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.create_title_edittext);
        note = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.create_note_edittext);
        remark = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.create_remark_edittext);

        create.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);
        noteslist.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==create) {
            nmanager = new NotesCRUDManager(this);
            nmanager.InsertNote(title.getText().toString(), note.getText().toString(), remark.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Note Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (v==clear){
            // clear all text inside Edittext
            title.setText("");
            note.setText("");
            remark.setText("");
        }

        else if (v==noteslist) {
            // start NotesList Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowNotesList.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        nmanager.closeDatabase();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is happening due to nmanager object not being initialized if user doesnt clicks.

change this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    nmanager.closeDatabase();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(nmanager != null){
        nmanager.closeDatabase();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> notelist seems like the error

Nope, read the stacktrace...

```
at plp.plpedia.developer.larriane.my_plpedia.MainNotes.onDestroy(MainNotes.java:60)
```

What happens when the Activity is destroyed and you didn't click on the create button?

Your database reference is null!

Move

```
nmanager = new NotesCRUDManager(this);
```

Into onCreate

Also, it might be beneficial to use SqliteOpenHelper classes